# Syntax error 'constant error

Tags: c++

I wrote a class which has a constructor that takes 2 parameters, but when I try to use an object of the class with those parameters I get that syntax error, I have tried everything I know to solve this but I couldn't.
the code:

```
class Vector2D{
public: 
Vector2D(int  xx, int yy) {}
Vector2D d(0, 0);
};
```

the error:

> Error C2059   syntax error: 'constant'    Project1

Comment: You can't create a `Vector2D` inside `Vector2D`.  That would be an infinite loop.  Please post a [mcve] that matches the error message

Comment: `Vector2D d(0, 0);` I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that line where it is, but it should not be there.

Comment: ok i used it outside the class and i got the same problem ?

Comment: *"outside the class"* where? in the main? in a header, in other class? at global scope?

Comment: yes in another class ( after including the header )

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are shooting for, the way you'd write the class is as follows

```
class Vector2D
{
public: 
    Vector2D() = default;
    Vector2D(int xx, int yy) : m_xx(xx), m_yy(yy) {}
private:
    int m_xx = 0;
    int m_yy = 0;
};
```

Your current issue is this line

```
Vector2D d(0, 0);
```

It looks like you are trying to declare a member variable `d` which is an instance of the class you are trying to define.

Comment: yes but when I copy your code and try to use an object of the class in another class ( after including the header ) I still get the exact same syntax error when I pass arguments to it like this Vecror2D d(2,4)

Comment: @HazemGamal Can you show your attempt at using this class as you describe?

Comment: i used it inside of another class it works when used in main() also works when used in gloabal scope but when i use it in another class it gives me that error